# Somebody know What is the name of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

This is an algorithm for converting an string to an integer:

```
int n = 0;
for (i = 0; i < digits.length; i++)
  n = n * 10 + (digits[i] - '0');
```

Somebody know what is the name of this algorithm? I need it for a reference in an article. I have used it but now I need some reference.

Comment: I think it's sooooo standard that there's probably no name for it...

Comment: It seems if the language supports type juggling (e.g. `- '0'` converts '0' to an integer) it would be easier to just use `0 + digits`.

Comment: Some call it `Avoid Atoi Algorithm (AAA)`.

Comment: Really, don't cite this procedure as an algorithm you used.  The procedure you use to print output to the screen is more complicated, and you don't cite that, do you?

Comment: My article is about algorithms, then I need reference for it. I don't talk about a specific language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had to give a name to it, most likely it would be `atoi` (like the C function)

Comment: No! I know that there is a name for the algorithm but I can't remember what is or where I read it.

Comment: @D.D.C you are probably thinking about Horner's method but its not really an algorithm per se

Comment: @FooBah I don't see any polynomials, but the idea is similar. But I think it comes off really weird to cite that scheme for this algorithm.

Comment: @MichaelNett The general form for base-`n` numbers is `a0 + a1*n+a2*n^2 + a3*n^3 ...` When you plug `n=10` then this procedure is essentially horner's method.